# Is the space position important in these spans?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility, whitespace

Starting from this DOM:

```
<h1><span>Lorem</span><span>Ipsum</span></h1>
```

For accessibility reasons, we had to add a space so that the two words are not adjacent (read as "Lorem Ipsum" and not "LoremIpsum"). Regular display is identical because of the CSS (display:block). So we have:

```
<h1><span>Lorem</span> <span>Ipsum</span></h1>
```

However, due to some JavaScript, it would be more convenient to have this:

```
<h1><span>Lorem</span><span> Ipsum</span></h1>
```

Is this totally equivalent? Could the space be mangled this way?

Comment: The short answer is it depends. If there's not much styling it won't matter. But if the spans have wildly differing styles it will matter.

Comment: Why not do it with CSS? Give one or the other `<span>` a `::before` or `::after` property.

Comment: @Pointy It should be spaced also (and especially) without CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two should be equivalent. White space is collapsed into a single space when inside an `inline` displayed object. Whether directly under the `<h1>`, or inside the `<span>`, it should be more or less the same. The main difference is that the whitespace in the second case will be styled according to the `span` styling.

See [section 9.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) for HTML 4 spec for instance.

Comment: So basically the spaces are really treated as other characters, they are never trimmed for instance?

Comment: Whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines) are collapsed into a sinlge (breaking) space and rendered as such, during `inline` and `inline-block` display settings.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is it depends.
If the `span`s aren't styled in a very distinct manner, there won't be any difference.
However if the `span`s do have a specific style that's typographically different from the `h1` it might show since the space will be styled by the `h1` in the first sample and the `span` in the second.

See the below example where the difference is brought forward by different styling:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
h1 span {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Lorem</span> <span>Ipsum</span></h1>
<h1><span>Lorem</span><span> Ipsum</span></h1>
```

Comment: So as in my case the CSS renders the same, I can assume there are no differences at all?

Comment: Yes. As long as you keep in mind that there's a space if you need to parse the text back with Javascript, for example, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples would be equivalent for the most part. The only noticeable difference that I would see is if you had some type of styling done with the span (which I assume you do). If there was styling then the style would be applied to the space if the space was inside the span. I personally like the space between the spans, because it looks better, but if it is easier to write some javascript, I would use the second.

Answer (score -1):

Having the space in between the two  would be more convenient if you plan to change the spans dynamically.
Other than that, it's totally equivalent.